# Replace EditFor to a chackbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

New to MVC, I am using a vs2019 template linked to CRM using CData. I have created an edit view. The new_fm-bankdata is a boolean field. The EditFor display a dropdown box with True / False / Not Set, with the current value displayed. How can I change this to a check box

`@ModelType xxxx.Contact
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Edit"
End Code

@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
@<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>Edit User : @Session("FullName")</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Id)

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.new_fm_bankdata, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.new_fm_bankdata, "Required", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

End Using

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to read more about [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.new_fm_bankdata, new {@class = "form-control"}})
```